# Puma shows al requests coming from 127.0.0.1 when behind nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I am having a problem where the only IP Address that shows up in my rails log is 127.0.0.1, it appears that the remote ip is not getting proxy passed. I am unsure of what I a missing. Nginx is custom compiled within an omnibus package. and I have that build script below as well. If anyone can give me some insight that would be greatly appreciated.

Nginx Build Recipe:

```
name "nginx"
default_version "1.9.10"

dependency "pcre"
dependency "openssl"

source url: "http://nginx.org/download/nginx-#{version}.tar.gz",
       md5: "64cc970988356a5e0fc4fcd1ab84fe57"

relative_path "nginx-#{version}"

build do
  command ["./configure",
           "--prefix=#{install_dir}/embedded",
           "--with-http_ssl_module",
           "--with-http_stub_status_module",
           "--with-http_gzip_static_module",
           "--with-http_v2_module",
           "--with-http_realip_module",
           "--with-ipv6",
           "--with-debug",
           "--with-ld-opt=-L#{install_dir}/embedded/lib",
           "--with-cc-opt=\"-L#{install_dir}/embedded/lib -I#{install_dir}/embedded/include\""].join(" ")
  command "make -j #{workers}", :env => {"LD_RUN_PATH" => "#{install_dir}/embedded/lib"}
  command "make install"
end
```

Nginx Config:

```
user smart-mobile smart-mobile;
worker_processes 1;
error_log stderr;
pid nginx.pid;
daemon off;

events {
  worker_connections 10240;
}

http {
  #log_format combined '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
  #                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
  #                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
  #
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;

  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_comp_level 2;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/json;

  proxy_cache_path proxy_cache keys_zone=smart-mobile:10m max_size=1g levels=1:2;
  proxy_cache smart-mobile;

  include /opt/smart-mobile/embedded/conf/mime.types;

  include /var/opt/smart-mobile/nginx/conf/smart-mobile.conf;
}
```

Nginx Site Config:

```
upstream smart_mobile {
  server unix:/var/opt/smart-mobile/puma/puma.socket;
}



  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 10.10.20.108;

    access_log /var/log/smart-mobile/nginx/smart-mobile-http.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/smart-mobile/nginx/smart-mobile-http.error.log;

    root /opt/smart-mobile/embedded/smart-mobile-rails/public;
    index index.html;

    ## Real IP Module Config
    ## http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html

    location / {
      if (-f /opt/smart-mobile/embedded/smart-mobile-rails/tmp/maintenance.enable) {
        return 503;
      }

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @ruby;
    }

    location @ruby {
      proxy_pass http://smart_mobile;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 402 /402.html;
    error_page 500 /500.html;
    error_page 502 /502.html;
    error_page 503 @maintenance;

    location @maintenance {
      if ($uri !~ ^/icos/) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /503.html break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Puma Config:

```
directory '/opt/smart-mobile/embedded/smart-mobile-rails'
threads 2,4
bind 'unix:///var/opt/smart-mobile/puma/puma.socket'
pidfile '/var/opt/smart-mobile/puma/puma.pid'
preload_app!

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
end

before_fork do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!
end
```

Comment: I have rebuild the application manually using only system packages and still getting the same result. This may be a Rails Application Issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my own fault I had all my proxy_set_headers before the try_files. I moved the proxy_set_header directives into the @ruby location block and removed the X-Real-IP header. Everything is working now thank you for all the input.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (puma 3.4.0):

```
# Serve static content if a corresponding file exists.
location / {
  try_files $uri @proxy;

  # NOTE: Parameters below apply ONLY for static files that match.

  expires max;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
  add_header By-Nginx "yes";     # DEBUG
}

# Serve dynamic content from the backend.
location @proxy {
  proxy_pass http://backend_for_www.site.com;

  proxy_pass_request_headers on;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

After some exploration, I've found out that:

- Puma is trained to look at HTTP header `X-Forwarded-For` specifically.
  Once it's passed correctly, Puma should hook it up.
  No configuration on Puma end is necessary.
- `request.headers["REMOTE_ADDR"]` will stay `"127.0.0.1"`, this doesn't change no matter how hard you try.
- Passing header `X-Real-IP` **does not** affect the logging issue anyhow.
  Basically you can use `set_remote_address header: "X-Real-IP"` in Puma configuration file to set "remote address of the connection" from this header.
  But Puma itself doesn't look in that direction I don't know any other software that does. Documented here: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/puma/3.2.0/Puma%2FDSL%3Aset_remote_address.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm just getting back to this issue. I will mark the answer correct once it works.